# SVM feature reduction

Tags: svm, libsvm

Suppose task where you need to classify texts using SVM. So before that you need to extract some features from texts. Suppose you pick up many of them and get huge vector. Is there any automatic approach (both theoretical and practical aspect of this question) to reduce features to make model simpler and so reduce test set error?

**Here my example:**

Suppose I have labelled data 
Positive class: (10, 2) (15, -130) (20, 0) 
Negative class: (5, -130) (0, 0) (-10, 2)
Here you may see that second parameter is "useless", could this fact be found automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/feature-selection-before-svm

Comment: Not quite I am asking for automatic approach based on SVM algorithm itself.